# Django 1.8: migrations break with AbstractBaseUser

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, django-1.8

I have a working Django 1.6 project that I'm upgrading to 1.8. I have a custom user model in app `mainapp` that looks like this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
```

`manage.py migrate` or `syncdb` fail with the following error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: gis, gunicorn, staticfiles, guardian, messages, captcha, corsheaders, bootstrapform
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, sites, auth, contenttypes, mainapp
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table guardian_userobjectpermission
    Creating table guardian_groupobjectpermission
    Creating table corsheaders_corsmodel
    Running deferred SQL...
    ...
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_permission" does not exist
```

I followed the answer in [Django 1.8 RC1: ProgrammingError when creating database tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194575/django-1-8-rc1-programmingerror-when-creating-database-tables) and ran makemigrations for the app (and all the other apps that can be migrated, including `auth`). No changes are detected for any of them and `migrate` continues to fail after this. How can I correct this?

**HACKY WORKAROUND:**
I can get the project running by commenting out all my apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`, then adding them in a specific order and running `migrate` as I go along. WTF... there has to be a proper way to do this.

Comment: You might need to edit your mainapp initial migration to add a dependency on auth.

Comment: @DanielRoseman How? I'm new to migrations.

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#migration-files) - just edit the `dependencies` list in your migration to reference `('auth', '0001_initial')`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's already there: `('auth', '0006_require_contenttypes_0002')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was one of the third party apps I was using that needed upgrading. Not that you can tell from the error.

Comment: Which 3rd-party app was it?

Comment: @mallyvai: if I remember correctly, it was django-guardian.

Comment: Noted... seems like another perms/auth related app running into issues here.. are your tests running now?