# heroku: relation "auth_group" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, syncdb, django-custom-user

I'm facing problem while doing syncdb on heroku.
I have a custom user model and when I try to sync,heroku gives this error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_group" does not exist
```

I tried python manage.py makemigrations but nothing is getting resolved.
Help me find the solution.

Comment: Similar question, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194575/django-1-8-rc1-programmingerror-when-creating-database-tables

Comment: This solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438332/django-i-get-a-relation-auth-group-does-not-exist-error-after-syncdb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had a similar problem. It seems that the auth module should be the first module to migrate but for some reason that isn't happening.

All what I did to solve this was

```
./manage.py migrate auth
```

Then

```
./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Nothing happend