# Django: I get a [relation "auth_group" does not exist] error after syncdb

Tags: django, postgresql

I started a new Django 1.8 project and realized that I missed something (i had done the initial migrations). I dropped the database (postgreSQL) and deleted `migration` folders from all my apps in order to start from scratch.

Now, when I 'syncdb' I get this error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_group" does not exist`

and when I `makemigrations` I get this:

`No changes detected`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is django.contrib.auth in INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: yes, also `django.contrib.admin` is in there, too (I don't know if that means anything).

Comment: Thanks! I assumed this was a default -.-

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Probably you should try to create `migrations` modules (folders named `migrations` with empty file named `__init__.py` inside of each directory) for your apps. And then run `manage.py makemigrations` again.

Comment: thanks! it worked! I never had this problem using South in previous Django versions. South recreated the migrations folders.

Comment: Worked for me too. But is that supposed to be a bug, or that's how upcoming migrations are supposed to work?

Comment: I think it's because a folder isn't a python package unless it has an __init__.py file, so it errored during it's sync. If you look at all of your project's folders you'll see blank init files in each.

Comment: in which folder should I put it?

Comment: @AminahNuraini in the folder of your app. If there is no folder 'migrations' with '__init__.py' inside the app folder, 'makemigrations' will ignore the app.

Comment: AFAICT, this is necessary when using Postgres (but not when using sqlite!), even when you have migrations turned off for your database (with this setting in settings.py: `MIGRATION_MODULES = {'default': None}`)

Answer (score 9):

The problem is on `no changes detected`. Please execute these commands with your app name. I guess you didn't add it (just like the mistake I did):

1. `python manage.py makemigrations myappname`
2. `python manage.py migrate myappname`

Answer (score 5):

Doing `./manage.py migrate auth` first didn't work for me, and every `./manage.py` command was throwing this error. My problem was that I was doing stuff with the `Group` manager in module scope.

If you have code like this in module scope:

```
customers_group = Group.objects.get(name='customers')
```

Move it inside a function that is called at runtime instead.

```
def xyz():
    ...
    customers_group = Group.objects.get(name='customers')
```

Answer (score 4):

The above error occurs when you have **django.contrib.admin** among the installed applications. 
Run these commands in their respective order.

```
**

./manage.py makemigrations 
./manage.py migrate auth
./manage.py migrate**
```

That worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Did not work for me. Adding the migration modules as suggested in other answer did.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem with Django2.2 migrations. I will post what helped in case someone is looking to fix this.

I commented out all urls to apps(like my_app.urls, your_app.urls) in main project `urls.py` and then ran `makemigrations`, it worked.
I think this error is due to some forms/views referring to model/fields that are not yet created. It seems django traverses `urls.py` to before making migrations

Answer (score 0):

It can be either:

- one of the pip dependencies from requirements.txt was using South

  had this error when running tests which do migration in Django 1.8.  Found the lib with issue by running tests in verbose mode. Consider upgrading the library to newer version.

> manage.py test -v 3

- one of the /migrations folder might still has old South migrations files. 
  It can be because others are still adding migrations when you are trying to upgrade Django. Use the following to make sure that the expected migrations files are present in each app.

> manage.py showmigrations

Answer (score 0):

One of your paths ("pointing urls.py on your core folder along with the settings.py") makes that problem occur  importing django.contrib.auth and directly using methods and properties of "auth" after calling those views

- Remove all migrations except "**init**.py" of each apps
- Go to projects urls.py and comment out all the paths
- run "heroku run python manage.py makemigrations"
- run "heroku run python manage.py migrate"

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions here, but nothing helped. Finally I commented out all the apps I created in `INSTALLED_APPS`, then called `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` for the remaining apps (like auth). Then I added my apps back one by one and called `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` again after each app.

This worked for me.