# Programming Error in deploying Django website on Heroku

Tags: django, sqlite, heroku, database-migration, heroku-postgres

I am learning Django and wanted to deploy the app on Heroku. upon following the Heroku documentation on deploying the app to the platform. It is throwing errors.

I have 2 apps in the project:

1. blog (for writing the blogs)
2. userAuthentication (user auth)

Please help!

**ERROR on Heroku deployed app:**

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "blog_categories" does not exist
LINE 1: ...categories"."name", "blog_categories"."name" FROM "blog_cate...
                                                             ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://sciencecreed.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "blog_categories" does not exist
LINE 1: ...categories"."name", "blog_categories"."name" FROM "blog_cate...
                                                             ^
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py, line 84, in _execute
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.4
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python39.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 29 Apr 2021 21:36:58 +0000
```

**ERROR on executing "heroku logs"**

[image: eroor 1]

[image: error 2]

[image: error 3]

[image: error 4]

The migrations work fine when running them locally with sqlite3 database but not on Heroku with PostgreSQL.

I tried running python manage.py makemigrations & python manage.py migrate on Heroku but no luck.

You can visit https://sciencecreed.herokuapp.com/ for the complete info of the error.

Comment: Run your migrations, e.g. via `heroku run python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: ProgrammingError relation does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980717/django-programmingerror-relation-does-not-exists)

Comment: The above better describes my issue but I tried the methods it suggested and no luck there.

Comment: There are others. I _strongly_ urge you to use the same database in development and production. They're not drop-in replacements from each other, e.g. see the accepted answer on [Relation does not exist - Django & Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55117984/354577)

Comment: And there's never any reason to run `makemigrations` on Heroku. By the time your code gets deployed you shouldn't have any model changes that would generate a migration. Generate migrations in development, commit the files, and apply them everywhere.

Comment: Hi, @Chris I saw some videos where the guy used sqlite3 (which comes with Django) and used a library called *psycopg2*  to "translate" the database to Postgres. I was hoping the same thing but this error came.

Comment: `psycopg2` doesn't translate anything. It's just a Python driver for PostgreSQL. SQLite is pretty lax on some things that Postgres won't like. You want that to fail _in development_, not in production.

Comment: Oh, thanks... But now at this point what should I do? 
I am currently in development and wanted to host as soon as possible. 
Now, this error is there... What will you suggest, I should do?
Thanks,

Comment: I suggest you read both of the links I provided in their entirety. So far it doesn't sound like your error is any different from them. If that doesn't help, consider doing your own search for other existing questions. If you can explain how your error is different from the ones I've already pointed to, please do.